# Can the kernel set the interval of the "hardware timer" of the CPU, and does the CPU have a dedicated hardware timer for scheduling?

Tags: timer, operating-system, kernel, cpu, scheduling

Based on my understanding, the CPU has a "hardware timer" that fires an interrupt when its interval expires.

The kernel uses this hardware timer to implement the scheduling mechanism for the processes, so if the hardware timer fires an interrupt with the number of `123`, the kernel will map this interrupt number to an interrupt handler that executes the scheduler code (which will decide which process to execute next).

I have two questions:

1. Can the kernel set the interval of the hardware timer, or is the interval a fixed number that can't be changed programmatically?
2. Does the CPU have a dedicated hardware timer for scheduling or is there many hardware timers, and the kernel can choose whichever timer it wants to use for scheduling?

---

***Edit:*** The hardware architecture I am more interested in is a PC, but I would like to know if other architectures (for example: a mobile phone, a raspberry PI, etc.) works in a similar way.

Comment: I think the answer is yes to both questions, but details are computer specific (and could be different on a PC laptop and on a RaspBerry Pi). You need to explicit the particular hardware architecture you are talking about. So *edit your question* to improve it

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I edited my question.

Comment: 'The kernel uses this hardware timer to implement the scheduling mechanism for the processes' well, that's being economical with the truth:)  It's more like 'The kernel uses this hardware timer to time out system calls and share out CPU when there are more ready/running threads than there are cores'.

Answer (score 0):

Details are hardware specific (might be different with various motherboards, chipsets, processors; read about [SouthBridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing))). Read about [High Precision Event Timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) (and [APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller)).

See also [OSDEV wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), notably [Programmable Interval Timer](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer).

(so the answer is usually yes to both questions)

Answer (score 0):

From early on, IBM-compatible PCs had PITs (Programmable Interval Timers): IBM PC and IBM PC XT had the Intel 8253, the IBM PC AT introduced the Intel 8254.

From the IBM PC Technical Reference from April 1984, page 1-11:

> > #### System Timers
> >
> > Three programmable timer/counters are used by the system as follows: Channel 0 is a general-purpose timer providing a constant time base for implementing a time-of-day clock, Channel 1 times and requests refresh cycles from the Direct Memory Access (DMA) channel, and Channel 2 supports the tone generation for the speaker. [...]

Channel 0 is exactly the "constant time base," the "interval" you are asking for. And, to answer your 1<sup>st</sup> question, it is changeable; it is the **Programmable** Interval Timer.

However, the CPU built into the original IBM PC was the Intel 8088, basically an Intel 8086 with an 8-bit data bus. Real Mode was the state of the art back then; Protected Mode was introduced some years later with the Intel 80286, so effective multitasking, let alone preemptive multitasking or multithreading, were of no concern in those days when DOS reigned the market.

Fast-forwarding to the IBM PC AT, the world was blessed with a Protected Mode-capable CPU, the Intel 80286, and the Intel 8254 was introduced, a "[...] superset of the 8253." (from the 8254 PIT datasheet). If you really want an in-depth understanding of the PITs, read the 8253/8254 datasheets linked at the bottom. It might also be worth looking at Linux. Since the latest kernels are way too complicated to really understand the particular parts in a matter of twenty minutes, I suggest you look at [Linux 0.01](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/linux-0.01.tar.gz), the very first release. `_timer_interrupt` in `kernel/system_calls.s` might be interesting and from there you can go wherever you want.

Regarding your 2<sup>nd</sup> question: there are multiple timer sources, but only one is suitable for interval timing, that is, channel 0. IBM-compatibles still comply with the system timer layout shown above. They retain the same functionality, but might add more on top of that or change how the hardware works and how it's packaged. Nowadays, additional timers do exist like high-resolution timers, but using them for interrupt timing instead would break compatibility.

---

- [Intel 8253 Datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/66098/INTEL/8253/+4W199U.lSElbzBvY+/datasheet.pdf)
- [Intel 8254 Datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/66099/INTEL/8254/+4W19-U.lSElbzBvv+/datasheet.pdf)
- [IBM PC Technical Reference](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/IBM_5150_Technical_Reference_6322507_APR84.pdf)
- [IBM PC AT Technical Reference](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/IBM_5170_Technical_Reference_1502243_MAR84.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> Can the kernel set the interval of the hardware timer, or is the interval a fixed number that can't be changed programmatically?

Your questions are ENTIRELY processor specific. Some processors have controllable timers. Others have timers that go off at fixed intervals. Most processors you are likely to encounter have adjustable timers, however.

> Does the CPU have a dedicated hardware timer for scheduling or is there many hardware timers, and the kernel can choose whichever timer it wants to use for scheduling?

Some processors have only one timer. Most processors these days have multiple timers.